# Is the composite order matrix-DDH secure?

Tags: discrete-logarithm, hardness-assumptions

I recently read a [paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/377.pdf) that proposed a matrix-DDH which is a matrix variant of DDH assumption. The brief definition is follows:

Let $G$ be a group of prime order $q$.
Then, the matrix-DDH says that it is hard to distinguish between two distributions:
$\{[A], [A\cdot w] \} \approx \{[A], [u], u\leftarrow \text{random} \}$.

Here, the bracket notation $[x]$ denotes the group element with discrete logarithm $x$.
For a vector $v = (v_1, \ldots,v_k)$, $[v]$ denotes a vector of the form $(g^{v_1}, \ldots, g^{v_k})$. For any matrix $A$, $[A]$ is similarly defined. That is, $[A]$ is a matrix of which $(i,j)$-th entry is $g^{A_{i,j}}$, where $A_{i,j}$ is the $(i,j)$-th entry of $A$.

The original paper only proves a case that $q$ is prime. On the other hand, when $q$ is a composite order, the matrix-DDH is still secure? I could not find any reference about this.

Comment: please clarify the question with definition of how the matrices come in

Comment: @kodlu Suppose that $A \leftarrow Z_q^{\ell \times k}, w \leftarrow \Z_q^k$ and $u\leftarrow \Z_q^\ell$. For a group $G$ of prime order $q$ with generator $g$, we use a notation [a] = g^a for any a.
Under this setup, matrix DDH assumption says that the advantage of distinguishing two distributions in the main body is negligible. My question is what happen $q$ is composite number instead of prime.

Comment: What is the vector $[w]$?

Comment: Given $w=(w_1,\cdots,w_k)$, $[w]$ is denoted by $([w_1], \cdots, [w_k])$. I apologize for many mistatkes. For a matrix $A$, $[A]$ is similarly defined.

Comment: Please put these clarifications into the question itself